# Get Azure DevOps Teams using .Net Client SDK

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, azure-devops, sdk

How to get Teams created under team projects on Azure DevOps Server using .Net Client SDK library?
I know how to get projects but I can't seem to find the call to retrieve the teams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these two links might help you

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/teams/get%20all%20teams?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Samples/ProjectsAndTeams/TeamsSample.cs

There are samples about how to get all Teams from the API.

```
IEnumerable<WebApiTeam> teams = teamClient.GetTeamsAsync(project.Id.ToString()).Result;
```

Comment: very helpful links. Though any idea how to get Sprints as well? I looked around in the URLs provided, I couldn't find it.